# Align text drawn on path with Direction.CCW

Tags: android, android-view

I have text which is drawn on path

```
path.addRect(left, pathTop, left + widthPart, pathBottom, Direction.CCW);
c.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 0, 0, textPaint);
```

Now this text is aligned like left-bottom. I want to align this text center-vertical.
How am I supposed to do that?
I've tried to use indent on

```
( pathTop - pathBottom - textInRect.width )/2
```

, but sometimes it's not properly in center.